# Inverse integral transform of $\cos(t-u)$

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-transforms

I have the following integral transform

$$ f(u) = \int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\cos(u-t)\,dt $$

where I know what $f(u)$ is (I have raw data rather than an analytical form) and I need to reconstruct $g(t)$.

While I can find online the inverse integral transforms for several kernels ([e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform#Table_of_transforms)) I can't find anything for this particular kernel.

Does anyone know the solution? Or how to derive it? Perhaps it can be rearranged into a well-known integral transform? Or a paper/textbook where the solution is given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ f(u) = \int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\cos(u-t)\,dt \tag 1$$
$$ f(u) = \cos(u)\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\cos(t)\,dt +\sin(u)\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\sin(t)\,dt $$

$\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\cos(t)\,dt=c_1 \tag 2$

$\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\sin(t)\,dt=c_2 \tag 3$

$$f(u)=c_1\cos(u)+c_2\sin(u) \tag 4$$

If $f(u)$ is not sinusoidal the equation $(1)$ is not valid. The problem has no solution.

If $f(u)$ is sinusoidal the equation $(1)$ is valid. You can fit the data with the sinusoidal function $(4)$  which gives the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ on the form of numerical approximates (Regression method).

Then one can find an infinity of functions $g(t)$ which satisfies Eqs.$(2)$ and $(3)$. The solution is not unique.

Comment: Thank you very much.